# Is it possible to update a clone database only with changes in the source database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ms-access, plsql

For reasons I'm not about to explain, We keep a Access database that is to be a copy of a subset of a larger oracle database. It is not feasible to refer to data directly in the Oracle database due to speed issues (don't ask).

Every time a specific application is opened the local Access database is updated from the newest data found to the time of opening the application. First of all this does not capture changes in the existing records. Secondly it does not take into account changes in the source database made after opening the application.

For this reason several checks may be needed when carrying out certain operations in the application. So is it possible to update the local Access database only with changes in the Oracle database in a smarter and faster way than the hard way I am imagining (I'm not a PL/SQL / SQL expert)? Possibly it might be sufficient to look for changes only after a certain date (stored in one of the fields of the recordset retrieved).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you aware that you can link Oracle tables and run queries in MS Access?

Comment: `archivelog`s may be a way. But I am not sure how you would replicate that to Access Database.

Comment: Are you looking to do this FROM Access or from the PSQL system?  If PSQL, why not put a trigger on the table for new records and have it send the New/Update/Delete statements information to the Access database.  I believe in PSQL you can link a database to it, but i may be confused with other derivatives of PSQL.

Comment: Why don't you just use a DateTimeModified field in every table. Then you could easily check for anything modified after a given date/time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into data replication beethween Oracle en MSAccess databases. For example thru an ODBS drive or sqlserver database. Just google "ms access oracle replication" an see if this solves your problem.